# antd: Radio buttons as cards

Tags: javascript, antd

I want to create cards with the radio buttons functionality, when a card is clicked it should show it as "selected" and remove the "selection" from the one that has been previously selected.

Any idea how to do it?

I am using the antd components.

Thanks in advance, if you need any extra code snippet just please let me know.

Comment: check if this [link](https://codepen.io/dromo77/pen/ZEQWyaZ) can help you

Comment: Using JS you can literally tie it to the state of a radio button, using CSS classes to change the look when its selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AntD Radio.Button accepts children so you can just try to give it a Card component.

I did something similar with a custom Icon

```
  <Radio.Group
    size="large"
    buttonStyle="solid"
    className="large-icons"
  >
    <Radio.Button value="Canine">
        <CustomIcon type="cute-dog" />
        Canine
    </Radio.Button>
    <Radio.Button value="Feline">
        <CustomIcon type="nice-cat" />
        Feline
    </Radio.Button>
  </Radio.Group>
```

Comment: can you specified that you are using the react lib ?